# Cannot Disable WPF Expander with a Style

Tags: c#, wpf, expander, isenabled

I created a style for my `Expander` control that's supposed to disable the expander if it's value is *false*, but it does not work at all. My expander is Enabled all the time, no matter if IsCheckedIn is true or false.

```
<Style x:Key="CollapseIsCheckedInExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCheckedIn}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And here is where I set the style of my expander in my datagrid:

```
<Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Expanded" Style="{DynamicResource CollapseIsCheckedInExpander}"/>
```

I have a property code-behind that's called "IsCheckedIn" and I set the value to *true* or *false* based on if the truck I'm checking in is already checked in or not.

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT:

Here is my class:

```
public class TruckItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    bool _isCheckedIn;
    public bool IsCheckedIn
    {
        get { return _isCheckedIn; }
        set
        {
            if (_isCheckedIn != value)
                _isCheckedIn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckedIn");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }        
}
```

And here is a snipped where I define my IsCheckedIn:

```
truckItem.TruckCurrentPhase = item.CurrentPhase; //Current value is "Not Started", so the IsCheckedIn value should be false in the code below
truckItem.IsCheckedIn = truckItem.TruckCurrentPhase == "Checked In" ? true : false;
```

**SOLUTION**

I found that my issue was using the RowHeaderTemplate. For some reason it did not pick up my bindings but the DataGridTemplateColumn did...

This does not work:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Expanded" Style="{StaticResource CollapseIsCheckedInExpander}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

This does work:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Expanded" Style="{StaticResource CollapseIsCheckedInExpander}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: why aren't you using the `IsCheckedIn`binding not directly in the Expander ?!

Comment: @Motivated I tried: `<Expander IsEnabled="{Binding IsCheckedIn}"/>` but it's still enabled all the time.

Comment: as Fabian recommended use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and alwas check if your `DataContext` is set correctly

Comment: @CareTaker22 Can you add code of `IsCheckedIn` definition and where you created this property?

Comment: If you set `IsEnabled` anywhere else it can't work because a Style Setter can't overwrite directly set values.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I tried both with the style and where I didn't bind directly to the expander and without the style and where I bind directly to the expander. Both of them didn't work. Only when I set `<Expander IsEnabled="False"/>` did it actually disable my expander.

Comment: @CareTaker22 Maybe you forgot about `Expander's` `DataContext`. You can look it in debug, does it match to your `TruckItems` object, does it `IsCheckedIn` property changes properly.

Comment: It doesn't work at RowHeaderTemplate, because the DataContext of RowHeader is not your Item. In CellTemplate it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build up a simple example (using Caliburn Micro for Binding and Notify...). It works fine for me.

With this you can test the Binding simply. Set the two Breakpoints while your Application is running. If you Change the Checkbox the Breakpoint1 should fire and Breakpoint2 should fire afterwards (I think for two times, to get actual value for the CheckBox and actual value for the Expander IsEnabled). If the breakpoints don't fire you have to check your DataContext (in your original code the DataContext need to be a truckItem not your ViewModel... have you checked this?).

xaml

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ExpanderEnable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Enalble Expander</CheckBox>
 <Expander IsEnabled="{Binding ExpanderEnable, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
     <TextBlock>TestText</TextBlock>
 </Expander>
```

cs

```
 private bool _expanderEnable;

 public bool ExpanderEnable {
     get 
     { 
         return _expanderEnable; //Breakpoint2
     }
     set {
         if (value == _expanderEnable) return; //BreakPoint1
         _expanderEnable = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
     }
 }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, but I still get the same results. My expander is still enabled all the time.

Comment: Can you see any Bindingproblems in your Output window belonging to IsCheckedIn,when you start your application? It would look llike: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference  or DataError 40... Did you try to set IsCheckedIn in constructor or to default value as false? Is it then disabled at startup?

Comment: Another thing is that you can use the Style as StaticResource (there is no need for a dynamic on ein my mind). <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Expanded" Style="{StaticResource CollapseIsCheckedInExpander}"/>

Comment: No sorry there is no warnings or errors in the output window, but when I set the expander like: `<Expander IsEnabled="False"/>` it disables my expanders, but it doesn't work when I bind it. I've also edited my question with my class and where I define my `IsCheckedIn` bool value.

Comment: have you still set the <Expander IsEnabled="True" /> and take your style like this: <Expander IsEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource }" />?

Comment: I removed the style and only used the `<Expander IsEnabled="False" />` - Works `<Expander IsEnabled="{Binding IsCheckedIn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>` - Doesn't work even though the bindings are correct.

Comment: Your solution will most definitely work, but I found out my problem. I will update my question with the solution I found. Thanks for all your input and effort ;)